# Update a field in one table with a minimum value in a field in a different table

Tags: sql, vb.net, ms-access, sql-update

I have two tables that both have a field named PostDate.

Both tables also have a field called LoadID.

In the first table there is one record for each LoadID.

In the second table there are multiple records for each LoadID and each record has a different value for PostDate.

I want to update the PostDate value in the first table with the Minimum PostDate value in the second table for each LoadID.

I can not figure out how to do this.

Comment: What have you tried and what happened when you tried it?  If you haven't tried anything then it's too soon to be posting a question here.

Comment: Is it the SQL part or the VB part which is causing you problem?

Comment: I was having problems with creating a sub-query with the min function. I tried everything I could think of but could not figure out how to group etc.

Answer (score 1):

Use a correlated subquery:

```
UPDATE first_table f
SET post_date = (
   SELECT min( post_date )
   FROM second_table s
   WHERE s.LoadID  = f.LoadID 
)
```

Comment: i get "Operation must use an updateable query" when I try this. It seems it should work. I am using Access 2000.

Answer (score 0):

@krokodilko answer will also work fine 
I am also suggesting a new solution for it

```
UPDATE f
SET f.post_date = s.Post_Date
from first_table f
inner join
(
   SELECT min( post_date ) Post_Date, LoadId
   FROM second_table s
   Group by LoadId
) s 
on s.LoadID  = f.LoadID
```